# Adjusting a converted OTF font for LaTeX

Tags: fonts, conversion, accents, opentype

I have bought OTF Adobe Garamond Pro and successfully converted it to use with LaTeX (using [`otfinst.py`](http://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/~jowens/code/otfinst/)). It works well including ligatures, old-style numerals, small caps, etc., but the problem is again with Latin characters, specifically *ď*, *ľ* and *ť* (`\v{d}`, `\v{l}`, `\v{t}`). Normally, the caron changes its shape so it looks like a comma rather than a wedge, but in this case, it is not working.

I have spent a considerable amount of time by researching the possibilities, yet came to no acceptable conclusion.

Could you please suggest how to fine-tune it while preserving proper kerning?

[image: Improper placement of carons.]

Fig. 1: The problematic characters.

---

**Edit (20. July 2011):**

Thanks to Ulrike's answer, I have realised that I forgot to change the encoding and the encoding file. After editing the script and another run, it works perfectly and I can finally typeset my documents using Garamond typeface. I shall accept the answer as it led me to the solution.

[image: Proper placement of carons.]

Fig. 2: Victory! :-)

Comment: Note that XeTeX and LuaTeX can use OTF fonts natively. Note also that EB Garamond is an excellent open-source Garamond font :-)

Comment: I think that caron over t is misplaced, it should be placed lower. also, it is very similar to apostrophe, better is to have distinct shape, like in EB Garamond.

Comment: @michal.h21 As far as I know, the original typeface did not include the letter _ť_, so there should not be an exact example to follow. This is how Adobe decided to make it and I think that it is very reasonable as the proportions and placement are the same as in case of _ď_ and _ľ_.

Comment: @Raphink Thank you for the suggestions, I am aware of the potential of XeTeX and LuaTeX, but I have to use LaTeX for various reasons. EB Garamond appears to be still in development, hence its usage could cause problems later.

Comment: @Harrold: XeTeX and LuaTeX *are* LaTeX (see `xelatex` and `lualatex`). They're "just" alternative LaTeX compilers to PDFTeX, but the language is strictly the same and 99% of the CTAN packages will work just the same. In EB Garamond, it's mostly the Italic that's currently in development (and almost finished, I'm using it in a book) and the bold face is not done yet. The rest is ready (including small caps) and of really good quality.

Comment: @Raphink My apologies, I meant pdfTeX. But as I think about it now, my impression of XeTeX and LuaTeX was partially wrong, I shall investigate the possibilities more carefully. XeTeX did not support microtypography the last time I checked and as far as I am aware, it does not create PDF files directly. LuaTeX appears to be in a too early stage and since I am using Mac OS X with Latexian (editor) which does not support it, LaTeX still seems to be a better choice. I may be wrong, I am not an expert in this area, not even advanced in XeTeX/LuaTex. I have been working with TeX only for ca. a year.

Comment: (Which is a long time, granted, by I had to use it for work rather than systematically investigate all the possibilities.)

Comment: @Harrold: XeTeX creates PDF directly with `xelatex`. Microtypography support is not complete but is partially supported in `microtype` 2.5 <beta-06> (see http://xetex.tk/mediawiki/index.php/Microtype_package_%28preliminary_version%29). Protrusion is supported, but not font expansion. Microtype with LuaTeX supports font expansion as well as protrusion.

Comment: @Raphink Thank you for the information, I shall certainly give it a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well in T1-encoding \v{d} etc are real chars. So if you don't get them either your font doesn't have the glyphs or something did go wrong with the reencoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%switch here to your font:

\begin{document}

\v{d}, \v{l}, \v{t}

\char164, \char169, \char180
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have just realised that I did not change the LY1 encoding... D'oh! :-) I am going to convert it again, the original font does have the glyphs.